# No such entity with customerId when using integration access token with REST API

Tags: rest-api, integration

This is with Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.5-p1 on their cloud service.

We have followed all the instructions for creating an integration token, toggling the setting to allow "OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens", and so on, as described at https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token/.

However, for any REST API request, for example:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ...' https://magento-url.com/rest/V1/orders/630
```

We are getting the following 404 error:

```
{"message":"No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue","parameters":{"fieldName":"customerId","fieldValue":19}}
```

This ID DOES seem to be associated with a customer that was deleted, BUT neither this order nor the integration token is associated with that customer account. Any ideas about what could be going on here? I know there was an issue with logging a non-existent customerId in earlier versions of Magento, but that does not seem related to what is going on here.